# VS2015 only offers last used source control option

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

When creating a new Visual Studio project I was originally asked if I want to use Git or TFS.
Now (after Update2 ?) it automatically selects the last one used without offering to change it.
e.g if I have worked on a git project it will automatically create a git repository without asking.

Is there an option to turn this behavior off again?

Comment: Are you creating the team project from web interface or from Visual Studio?

Comment: Directly from VS with the "New Project"-wizard. It originally hat a checkbox on there "add to source control" this is now either "create git repo" or opens a dialog to select the collection to add to. Originally it opened a dialog that asked you to choose git or tfs.

Comment: This is a Visual Studio project, not a TFS Team project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now depends on the selected Source Control provider in the settings. I assume that Microsoft has checked their usage statistics and have found that most people rarely switch between them once they've made their choice.

Either connect to a TFVC or Git repo first in the Team explorer window or switch the Source Control provider in the settings dialog of Visual studio.

I can't find a setting in the Settings dialog which allows you to choose every time. It may be that there is a registry setting that may influence this behavior, but I haven't found it.